# Selenium Webdriver PHPUnit: Possible to wait on whole function instead of element?

Tags: php, selenium

So there are lots of ways to make selenium wait such as

```
sleep(1); // sleeps for 1 second
```

or

```
while ($this->conditionIsFalse()) { sleep(500); }
```

or

```
waitForPageElement
```

etc... 
These are for a specific element but is it possible to create a script so that selenium waits for each single element no matter what? Or a pageload etc...

So basically it would work for the whole function and not just the current element that you are looking for. If you search for 50+ items on a page or multiple pages I rather have something that makes selenium wait for every pageload/element that writing after each search waitForPageElement ...

Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is **implicit wait** for all elements:

```
function setUpPage() {
    $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(25000);
}
```

[Selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits):

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

Moreover, you always can write a new function, which waits for every element, and use it instead of default methods.

```
protected function _waitAndFind($selector) {
        $element = $this->waitUntil(function($testCase) use ($selector) {
            try {
                $element = $testCase->_byQuery($selector);
                if ($element->displayed()) {
                    return $element;
                }
            } catch (PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException $e) {}
        }, 8000);
        return $element;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid implicitWait if possible. `implicitWait` will allow us to writing bad code easier. For example, it allows us writing code which don't handle race conditions.

Comment: @whhone what would you suggest beside implicitwaits?